# debug transaction in remix-ide not working

Tags: contract-development, remix

i want to debug a transaction in remix-ide, connected to my cpp-ethereum node on ropsten. When i input tx-hash and press play button nothing happens.
What went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can only debug transactions which were executed using the JS VM.

Comment: Are you sure? I have heard otherwise.